# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'FrameTable' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, tkinter, frames

I want to hide the frames on click button in Tkinter. The problem is table are 
not hidden and overwrite the previous frame

---------Search Frame---

```py
if(C1.get()=="Emp_ID"):
    tableframe=Frame(SearchFrame,bg="#4c5d34")
    style = ttk.Style().configure("Treeview.Heading",background="#2b411c",foreground="black",relief=GROOVE,font=('Palatino linotype',10,"bold"))
    treeview=ttk.Treeview(tableframe,column=("ID","Name","Department","Status","Duty Time","Rank","In Time","Out Time"),show='headings',height=18)
    treeview.column("ID",width=150)
    treeview.column("Name",width=150)
    treeview.column("Department",width=150)
    treeview.column("Status",width=150)
    treeview.column("Duty Time",width=150)
    treeview.column("Rank",width=150)
    treeview.column("In Time",width=150)
    treeview.column("Out Time",width=150)
    treeview.heading("#1",text="ID")
    treeview.heading("#2",text="Name")
    treeview.heading("#3",text="Department")
    treeview.heading("#4",text="Status")
    treeview.heading("#5",text="Duty Time")
    treeview.heading("#6",text="Rank")
    treeview.heading("#7",text="In Time")
    treeview.heading("#8",text="Out Time")
    #treeview.bind("<Double-1>",onDoubalclick)
    treeview.pack(pady=30)
    tableframe.pack()
    FrameTable.pack_forget()


elif(C1.get()=="Transport"):
    FrameTable=Frame(SearchFrame,bg="#4c5d34")
    style = ttk.Style().configure("Treeview.Heading",background="#2b411c",foreground="black",relief=GROOVE,font=('Palatino linotype',10,"bold"))
    treeview=ttk.Treeview(FrameTable,column=("Vichle Type","Vichle No","Driver ID","Status","In Time","Out Time","Date","Source","Destination"),show='headings',height=18)
    treeview.column("Vichle Type",width=150)
    treeview.column("Vichle No",width=150)
    treeview.column("Driver ID",width=150)
    treeview.column("Status",width=150)
    treeview.column("In Time",width=150)
    treeview.column("Out Time",width=150)
    treeview.column("Date",width=150)
    treeview.column("Source",width=150)
    treeview.column("Destination",width=150)

    treeview.heading("#1",text="Vichle Type")
    treeview.heading("#2",text="Vichle No")
    treeview.heading("#3",text="Driver ID")
    treeview.heading("#4",text="Status")
    treeview.heading("#5",text="In Time")
    treeview.heading("#6",text="Out Time")
    treeview.heading("#7",text="Date")
    treeview.heading("#8",text="Source")
    treeview.heading("#9",text="Destination")
    #treeview.bind("<Double-1>",onDoubalclick)
    treeview.pack(pady=30)
    FrameTable.pack()
```

The error is:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'FrameTable' referenced before assignment

Answer (score 0):

```
tableframe=Frame(SearchFrame,bg="#4c5d34")
```

I believe you meant to call the variable `FrameTable`.

Otherwise the call to `FrameTable.pack_forget()` will fail because the variable hasn't been assigned to.